# How to only update list within list based on index in python, without updating all lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to create a matrix that identifies how many times an activity follows the next activity.
I have a list of activities linked to IDs in chronological order, as such;

[image: Activity overwiew]

The output I am trying to create would specify the number of times Activity X follows Activity Y, resembling the following;

[image: Example output]

For which I need a dataframe such as

```
df_probabilty matrix = [[0, 2, 0],[0, 1, 2],[0, 0, 0]]
```

This is an example dataset to test the problem:

```
df_Data1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], \
"Activity": ['Enter', 'Check', 'Check', 'Leave', 'Enter', 'Check', 'Leave']})
```

First I create a list of different activities in dataset

```
states = df_Data.Activity.values
set_states = set(states)
list_states = list(set_states)
```

Next I create a list of lists

```
next_states = [0] * len(list_states)
next_states1 = [next_states] * len(list_states)
```

And now I want to increase the value in the list corresponding to the *activity_from* at the index of the *activity_to* with the following code;

```
for x in range(len(df_Data) - 1):
    state_from = df_Data.Activity.iloc[x]
    state_to = df_Data.Activity.iloc[x + 1]
    if df_Data.ID.iloc[x] == df_Data.ID.iloc[x + 1]:
        next_states1[list_states.index(state_from)][list_states.index(state_to)] += 1
```

However, the value at the nth element in **every** list is updated with this code, so I get:

```
          Enter  Leave  Check
Enter      0      2      3
Leave      0      2      3
Check      0      2      3
```

Can someone explain where I am going wrong? How do I only update the list corresponding to the *Activity_from*?

Comment: `next_states1 = [next_states] * len(list_states)` creates a list of list-references, where each reference will point to the same underlying list in memory - that means you only really have one actual unique and distinct list. Any changes or mutations you attempt to apply to the underlying list through ANY of these list references will be reflected in all other references, since they all point to the same underlying list in memory. What you actually meant to do is `next_states1 = [next_states.copy() for _ in range(len(list_states))]`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for me! Shouldn't have taken a shortcut in creating my list of lists in hindsight

Answer (score 0):

Paul M. solved my question. The problem was not in my for loop, but in how I created the list of lists *next_stages1*. Quote:

`next_states1 = [next_states] * len(list_states)` *creates a list of list-references, where each reference will point to the same underlying list in memory - that means you only really have one actual unique and distinct list. Any changes or mutations you attempt to apply to the underlying list through ANY of these list references will be reflected in all other references, since they all point to the same underlying list in memory. What you actually meant to do is* `next_states1 = [next_states.copy() for _ in range(len(list_states))]`